# Showing a List View when a button is clicked: Android

Tags: android, list, view

I am trying to implement a drop down list when a button is clicked.

So,  I have a text view and a button in a navigation bar(nav.xml) and a corresponding list view. This navigation bar is included in another page( products.xml)

when the button is clicked i get the list view right below the button(which is what i want to acheive) but its my moving all the contents on the current page downwards, even the text view which is placed in nav bar  moved downwards.

I am totally new to Android, any sample examples or a way how to achieve it
???

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need a [Spinner](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html). It's the equivalent of a drop down list for Android. You can find an example [here](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-spinner-example/).

Answer (score 0):

So, for our need we need to use ListPopupWindow. 
The link to official description:

> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListPopupWindow.html

Let's dive in the code:

we have our own method:

```
    public void downloadBtnSelected(View anchor) {
            final ListPopupWindow lpw = new ListPopupWindow(this);
            String[] data = { ".png", ".pdf", ".jpg", ".jpeg" };
            PopupAdapter pa = new PopupAdapter(data, this);
            lpw.setAdapter(pa);

            //setting up an anchor view
            lpw.setAnchorView(anchor);

            //Setting measure specifications. I'v used this mesure specs to display my
            //ListView as wide as my anchor view is
            lpw.setHeight(android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            lpw.setWidth(anchor.getRight() - anchor.getLeft());

            // Background is needed. You can use your own drawable or make a 9patch.
            // I'v used a custom btn drawable. looks nice.
            lpw.setBackgroundDrawable(this.getResources().getDrawable(
                    android.R.drawable.btn_default));

            // Offset between anchor view and popupWindow
            lpw.setVerticalOffset(3); 

            lpw.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                        long arg3) {
                              /// Our action.....
                    lpw.dismiss();

                }
            });
            lpw.show();

        }
```

and the button with an onClickListener to call this method:

```
Button btn = new Button(this);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                downloadBtnSelected(v);

            }
        });
```

we pass the View v argument as our anchor, in order to let our PopupWindow to know where to display itself. It will be displayed in the bottom-left corner of our anchor view if there is enough room below. If not- it will displa